# Android Studio Private method becomes public final after compile

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin, proguard, android-r8

Using android studio AGP 7.0, Java 11 and minifyEnabled=true

following is my method

```
private void init(){
}
```

**after compile this becomes public final init()** due to which I am getting run time crash saying LinkageError how come access specifier is getting change after compile?

Comment: this is not a valid method definition in java

Comment: can you share the whole crash stack?

Answer (score 1):

R8 does whole program optimization, and if the method does not have a keep rule R8 can do whatever it wants with the method including changing modifiers. If you want to make sure the method stays you can add a keep rule like this:

```
-keep class <class name holding method> {
  private void init();
}
```

then the method should not be touched by R8.

Is the `LinkageError` caused by adding code at runtime which is not processed by R8? For whole program optimization and boundaries to code not known to R8 must be covered by a keep rule.